# Python look for specific file in all subdirectories and copy it to another directory/

Tags: python, loops, copy, subdirectory

I have a folder in C:/Print with thousands of directories. They are named with numbers. Each directory contains subdirectories that may be named differently.

I want to input a number, then the program has to go into the directory that is named like the input and check ALL subdirectoriesfor the file that is named just like this input but with .tif extension and then copy it to another directory.

Example:

Input "63783"

C:/Print/63783/FCB/63783.tif -> copy it to D:/HotFolder

Can I please get some help?

Comment: Have you already discovered the `os` module?  You can use `os.listdir`, `os.path.isdir`, and `os.path.join` to scan and traverse directories.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to help you out but I think we're gonna need a little more information, is there a Discord account or server that I can contact you at?
Try this code, see if it works:

```
import os, shutil

number = int(input("Etner number: "))

path = "C:\\Print\\" + str(number)
os.chdir(path)
destination = "D:\\HotFolder"
path_list = os.listdir()

for sub_dir in path_list:
    sub_path  = path+ "\\" +sub_dir
    os.chdir(sub_path)
    files = os.listdir()
    if str(number) + ".tif" in  files:
        source = sub_path + "\\" + str(number) + ".tif"
        shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Comment: Can you please contact me at kevinusepp@gmail.com ?

Comment: I'll get in touch.

Comment: It doesn't work

line 11, in <module>
    sub_path  = path+"\\"+sub
NameError: name 'sub' is not defined

Comment: Change that to "sub_dir", the iterative variable of the loop.

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work. I tried multiple changes to the code.

Comment: I've edited my code yet again, this time I ran some test-cases and they should work...

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your effort but it doesn't work for me. Also, I need it to copy the file even if it's directly stored in C:/Print folder. If it's not there, then it should look for it further (in subdirectories). But it doesn't work for subdirectories also :/

Comment: Can you please try to make it like that: if there is a file called like [input] in C:/Print/[input]/, then copy it to D:/HotFolder, elif there is no file called like [input] in C:/Print, then look for this file in all subdirectories and then copy this file to D:/Hotfolder/.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f_name(some_input):
    import os, shutil

    src_path = "src_dir_path"
    src_path = os.path.join(src_path, some_input)  # dir path to look for
    dst_path = "dst_dir_path"

    if not os.path.isdir(src_path):  # no directory named <some_input>
        return  

    if not os.path.isdir(dst_path):  # destination folder check
        os.mkdir(dst_path)  

    copy_targets = [(root, filename) for root, _, filenames in os.walk(src_path) for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".tif")]

    for root, filename in copy_targets:
        origin = os.path.join(root, filename)
        dest = os.path.join(dst_path, filename)
        shutil.copyfile(origin, dest)  # copy file
```

Comment: Come to think about it, this wouldn't work if there are multiple files with same name under different depth of the target directory.